# How to make an alias in root permament?

Tags: linux, alias

I did with an especific user, but i can't do that when the user is root **(I know user root is not recomendable to use, but in my current job security policies are null in some systems and we want to make an easy way for a normal user to execute a program)** when i restart the `tty` or the machine all changes are rolled back, and i wanted to find `.bash_rc` for `root` but it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a system wide bashrc which can be found in `/etc`. Making a change in the system wide bashrc will make it available for all. It is usually located at `/etc/bash.bashrc`
Do not forget to source it.
`. /etc/bash.bashrc`

Comment: ok, it works big thx.

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

When bash initializes a non-login interactive bash shell on a Debian/Ubuntu-like system, the shell first reads `/etc/bash.bashrc` and then reads `~/.bashrc`.

The reason that `/etc/bash.bashrc` does not appear in normal bash documentation is that it is a feature added by Debian and adopted by Ubuntu.

The Debian version of bash is compiled with a special option (`-DSYS_BASHRC`) that makes bash read `/etc/bash.bashrc` before `~/.bashrc` for interactive non-login shells.  So, on Debian systems, `/etc/bash.bashrc` is to `~/.bashrc` as `/etc/profile` is to `~/.bash_profile`.

Thus, `/etc/bash.bashrc` is documented in the Debian and Ubuntu man pages but not in man pages from other distributions that do not support this feature.
`/etc/bash.bashrc` has been adopted beyond Debian circles in distros like Arch Linux, MSYS2 and thereby Git Bash.

Answer (score 0):

Or, a 'thinking outside of the box' solution is to just see where other aliases are defined in /etc/profile.d/* and simply add another to the file.

```
echo "alias ll='ls -al'" >> /etc/profile.d/dircolors.sh
```

That should do the trick!